# Bash script and regex issue

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04

Let's imagine that on my server, i have the following files :

```
foo@bar:/var/log/foo$ ls
fooFile1 fooFile2 logFile logFile.1 logFile.2
```

I wanted to create an archive containing every file but logFile.*. So I came up with the command :

`foo@bar:~$ tar -czf foo.tar.gz /var/log/foo/!(logFile.*)`

And it works fine ! However, when trying to create a script which does the same job :

```
#!/bin/bash

tar -czf foo.tar.gz /var/log/foo/!(logFile.*)
```

I came across the following error :

```
./test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '('
./test.sh: line 3: 'tar -czf foo.tar.gz /var/log/foo/!(logFile.*)'
```

The problem is not tar related (I met the same issue using `ls` instead of `tar`)

I don't understand where this error is coming from. Could anyone tell me where i am wrong ?

Met on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place this line just below shebang:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

to enable extended glob option in your script.

`!(logFile.*)` is extended glob pattern that requires enabling `extglob`

Comment: It is worth pointing out explicitly that this option is enabled by default in an interactive shell, which is the cause of the difference in behaviour.

Comment: I will need to look more into it. Thanks to both of you !